# Import operators from TLA+ module into another file

Tags: distributed-computing, tla+

Suppose that we have these operators in `tools.tla` file:

```
---- MODULE PT ----
Max(x, y) == IF x > y THEN x ELSE y
Min(x, y) == IF x < y THEN x ELSE y
=====
```

and we want to pass values (like arguments in programming languages such as python) and use these in another file, call it `use.tla`, to just use Max and Min without reimplementing them; How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar problem and that's my solutions:

> File -> Open module -> Add TLA+ module -> tools.tla

The empty tools.tla will be created, write your codes.

Go back to another file and

> EXTENDS tools